# NSPredicate with relation

Tags: core-data, nspredicate

I have a problem fetching all core data entities with a given predicate. My model looks like this . `Player` has a one to many relationship to `Weapon` and `Player` has a one to one relationship to `Metadata`

I want to list all `Weapons` belonging to a `Player` that has a `selected` attribute of `Metadata` set to true.

I use this predicate

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ALL player.metadata.selected == %@", @YES];
```

but I'm getting the error

```
The left hand side for an ALL or ANY operator must be either an NSArray or an NSSet.'
```

What am I doing wrong?

cheers,
Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reform your query. The '**ALL**' and '**ANY**' keywords are supposed to be used with to many relations. You have one to many relation from Player to weapons. But, then if you reverse the relation, you will see that the relation is many to one. So, each weapon has only one player.

```
Player <---->> Weapon

Weapon <<---> Player
```

So, if you change your predicate so something like this, it should work fine,

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"player.metadata.selected == %@", @YES];
```

Comment: That works, thanks. The problem now is that `-[NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate controllerDidChangeContent:]` does not seem to be called when the selected player changes.